# Get first trimmed strings from a multiline text

Tags: javascript, regex

My multiline input `string`:

```
123
 2345 a

ab_cd: xxxx
   123abc     456
:y
```

Want I'd like to get is the first match of each line where the pattern `[0-9a-z_]{1,100}` fits - ignoring white space in the beginning and empty lines.

So my expected result would be:

```
123
2345
ab_cd
123abc
```

My pattern doesn't seem to work:

```js
$entries = string.match(/^(?:\s*)([a-z0-9_]{1,100})(?:.*)$/gm);
```

The non-capturing group seems to be ignored. I get:

```js
[ "123", " 2345 a", " ab_cd: xxxx", "   123abc     456" ]
```

Only `:y` is correctly ignored. What am I doing wrong here? Although I have added this tag, I guess it is not a JS problem...

**Edit**: I would be happy to solve the problem with the regex pattern, not with JS means.

Comment: What are the non-capturing groups *for*? Wouldn't `/^\s*([a-z0-9_]{1,100}).*$/gm` suffice? (Or even just `/^\s*([a-z0-9_]{1,100})/gm`?)

Comment: @Biffen I thought I have to do declare explicitly what I not want. I want to get only `([a-z0-9_]{1,100})`. Probably, I haven't fully understood.

Comment: That's not quite how it works. As long as you wrap what you *want* in a group, you can just get that part by its group number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^[ \t]*([0-9a-z_]{1,100})/gm
```

And grab the value in Group 1.

If you need to also match uppercase letters, just use

```
/^[ \t]*(\w{1,100})/gm
         ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB9eW1/1)

```js
var re = /^[ \t]*(\w{1,100})/gm; 
var str = '123\n 2345 a\n\nab_cd: xxxx\n   123abc     456\n:y';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

**Pattern details**: It uses `/gm` flags - global and multiline modifiers to match all substrings the pattern can find and to make `^` match the start of lines.

- `^` - start of a line
- `[ \t]*` - 0+ spaces or tabs
- `([0-9a-z_]{1,100})`  - Group 1: 1 to 100 letters, digits, or `_`. If uppercase are also to be matched, use `\w` instead.

Comment: Can it be that it doesn't exactly work with when using match() function? There, the trailing whitespace is still present. Of course I can fix this with JS but it should be also possible with the pattern. Or not? And using `\s` instead of `[ \t]` is fine?

Comment: `String#match()` [does not keep captured substrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if the regex is declared with a global modifier `/g`.

Comment: I did not use `\s` on purpose since `\s` may use newline symbols. If you need to match empty lines, you may use `\s` instead of `[ \t]`. As an alternative to `[ \t]`, you may also use `[^\S\r\n]` to only match horizontal spaces.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying this. Using `match()` was obviously another problem. With your approach it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with **split-trim-join** formula

```
var output = string.split("\n").map( function(val){
  return val.trim()
}).join("\n");
```

More cross platform way (taking care of `\r` as well)

```
var output = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n").split("\n").map( function(val){
  return val.trim()
}).join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You regex can look something like:

```
/^[\s]*([\da-z_]{1,100})/gm
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ9iQ7/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of a line
[\s]* match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
1st Capturing group ([0-9a-z_]{1,100})
    [0-9a-z_]{1,100} match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: {1,100} Between 1 and 100 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
        a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
        _ the literal character _
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```